# Freeze columns in Google Sheets for multiple users

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way for multiple users working on a Google Sheets to freeze columns and rows the same way filter view works?

Comment: Hopefully freezing for multiple users is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

No,  that isn't currently possible.

However, if the spreadsheet is used for viewing data (and not entering or modifying) you could make a new spreadsheet for each user, and use `importRange` from the "master" spreadsheet in each copy's "A1" cell. Each copy can then freeze/hide/filter as they please and their data will update almost in real-time as the master spreadsheet changes.
One dissadvantage is that you will lose some collaboration because making a cell comment etc will only be in each user's copy, so for adding comments or modifying you need to go to the master.

As a bonus, you can add an extra sheet on each of the copies and put a link to the master spreadsheet there so its easy to go to the master.


`importRange` : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

Comment: Has this been changed since 2015? Is there such freezing option implemented today?